# Can I move a drain without moving the vent too?

Tags: plumbing, drain, relocating

I want to move the kitchen sink to the other side of the kitchen (approx. 10 feet away). Can I just extend the pipe and rely on the existing vent?

Answer (score 5):

You don't provide much context to this question, but the short answer is there's a maximum distance between the trap and the vent (should be specified by your local code). If the vent is too far away, the sink won't drain well.

[image]

As you can see, for a 2" pipe (typical), you can only go 5' (but of course: check your local building codes for specifics). 10' is definitely too far.

Remember also you need to maintain a slope on the waste line (typically 1/4" per foot).

If you can run the vent line over to the new location as well, it may be acceptable. A picture/diagram of what you're doing would help provide a better answer.